# calling a function with request parameter in controller fails in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have this route:

```html
Route::post('apply/upload/image/{type}', 'DLMM\News\Http\Controllers\ApplyController@upload');
```

and upload function in my ApplyController is:

```
public function upload($type, Request $request)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'title_news': {
            upload_main_pic_news($request);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public function upload_main_pic_news(Request $request)
{
    $validation = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(),
        ['mainImage' => 'required|image|max:1000',],
        ['required' => 'عکسی انتخاب نشده است.', 'image' => 'فایل انتخاب شده عکس نمی باشد.', 'max' => 'حداکثر اندازه عکس می تواند 1000 کیلوبایت باشد.',]);

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
        $fileName = $request->file('mainImage')->getClientOriginalName(); // renameing image
        $request->file('mainImage')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'image uploaded'
        ], 200);
    }

    $errors = $validation->errors();

    //$errors =  json_encode($errors);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $errors
    ], 422);
}
```

in this Scenario, function upload_main_pic_news($request) did not call. what is wrong?

thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: What is "this scenario"? What request did you do?

Comment: I encounter with this error : Call to undefined function DLMM\News\Http\Controllers\upload_main_pic_news. upload_main_pic_news function exists but the error message says undefined?. why we could not to call a function in controller. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
upload_main_pic_news($request);
```

To:

```
$this->upload_main_pic_news($request);
```

`upload_main_pic_news()` is a class method not a function in the global scope.

Hope this helps!